# Asp.net Page Web Method does not work on server, but on localhost it works fine

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

Page Samples/jssample2.aspx

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()] 
public static string HelloPage()
{
    return "g"; }
}
```

The jQuery:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://myhost.com/Samples/jssample2.aspx/HelloPage",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json"  });
```

Looks like my web service(asmx) is disable( when i publish it to server)
But i can go in my browser to Myhosting.com/jssample2.aspx/HelloPage  (and i see default soap descriptio

In FIDDLER POST http://myhost.com/Samples/jssample2.aspx/HelloPage HTTP/1.1 Fiddler Response HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
jquery.ajax error also return 404. Maybe i ndee add something to web.config? or to my web pethods(attributes)?
IIS SETTINGS 
.asmx D:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
My httpHandlers

```
<httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
```

I just create simple solution and publish it to web server all works fine. Looks like problem was in path

Comment: you should provide error messages and describe problem more properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was in web.config.
i remove router settings an add in httpmodules section

```
<add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Comment: Hey, Can you paste your full web.config file ? I am having same problem.